# Excel similar or comparison between two sheets and color row

Tags: microsoft-excel, comparison

I would like to compare two sheets (sheet1 and sheet2), and color a compleet row in sheet2 when for example 1 or more the same numbers are found in sheet1,

I came this far but then everything gets blurry.

=SIMILAR(sheet1A:A;sheet2!A:A;)

Comment: Case A:
Sheet1: 1 2 3 
Sheet2: 1 5 6
Case B:
Sheet1: 1 2 3 
Sheet2: 4 1 6
Case C:
...???
Could you specify your request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you are interested only in the first 100 rows. Then:

1. define the following name: int2 for Sheet2!$A$1:$A$100
2. define for cells
   A1:A100 in Sheet1 the following
   formula for conditional format:
   =SUM(--(ISERROR(MATCH($A$1:$A$100,int2,0))=FALSE))>0